# Disable Payment methods option on PayPal Page (PayPal NVP)

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-nvp

Hi I am using PayPal with NVP, 
Following is the request to SetExpressCheckout

```
        string returnURL = "http://localhost:50325/GetExpressCheckout.aspx" + "?amount=" + Amount + "¤cy=AUD";
        string cancelURL = returnURL.Replace("ReviewOrder", "ExpCheckOut");
        string strCredentials = "USER=" + strUsername + "&PWD=" + strPassword + "&SIGNATURE=" + strSignature;
        string strNVP = strCredentials;
        strNVP += "&PAYMENTACTION=Sale&AMT=" + Amount + "&BILLINGTYPE=MerchantInitiatedBilling" + "&RETURNURL=" + returnURL;
        strNVP += "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=25&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=Item1";

        strNVP += "&CANCELURL=" + cancelURL;
        strNVP += "&METHOD=SetExpressCheckout&VERSION=" + strAPIVersion + "&NOSHIPPING=1";
        HttpWebRequest wrWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strNVPSandboxServer);
        wrWebRequest.Method = "POST";
        // write the form values into the request message
        StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(wrWebRequest.GetRequestStream());
        requestWriter.Write(strNVP);
        requestWriter.Close();
        // Get the response.
        HttpWebResponse hwrWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)wrWebRequest.GetResponse();
        StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(wrWebRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
        // and read the response
        string responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
        responseReader.Close();
        return responseData;
```

1) After i got redirected to PayPal Page i can see **Payment methods** option. I want to disable that **Payment methods  *change*** option.

[image: Payment Methods]

2)**Or** if i click **change** link, i can see an option as **Bank account(eCheque)**, i want to disable that option too. Following is the image.
[image]

Any help on this please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got it. This might be useful to others.
This can be done on merchnats account.

Go to Profile after logging as merchant

Profile --- Payment receiving preferences ----

Block the following payments:
Payments by eCheque on your website. NOTE: You may not block eCheque payments on eBay.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to just disable the eCheck possibility you can set PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ALLOWEDPAYMENTMETHOD ='InstantPaymentOnly'

Comment: Hi I have added PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ALLOWEDPAYMENTMETHOD ='InstantPaymentOnly' in the setexpresscheckout method. But still it is showing Bank account(eCheque) option and also an extra option "Credit/debit card" added. I want only PayPal balance option and not other two options. Please help me.